# Getting the index of a current element across all matched elements in the DOM

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have a DOM structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="chapter">
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
</div>
<div class="chapter">
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   <section class="current"></section>
   <section></section>
</div>
<div class="chapter">
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
   <section></section>
</div>
```

I want to get the index number of the section with a class of "current", across all sections. In this example the index of that would be 5, since it's the 5th section tag and contains a class of current.

How do I get this with jQuery?

I've started with this to get a list of all sections in the dom:

```
var sections = $('section');
```

I've tried things like this to try and get the result I want:

```
alert($(sections+'.current').index());
```

That returns a js error.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your code `$('section')` would return you all the sections as a jquery object. Amongst them to get the index of a section which has a class of `current` you could do this:

```
sections.index($(".current"));
```

This would return you a relative index of the section with class current, which would be 4 as 
`$('sections')` would return you a jQuery object Array(0 indexed) which contains all the sections elements. So the element which matches is the 5th element and index would return 4. 
Hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alokswain/K6BZv/2/) helps.

Comment: This seems like it should work, in fact, i tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/uae2U/ and it does, but unfortunately in my code it's returning -1. This gets me closer though, so thanks!

Comment: If its returning -1 then there is probably some mistake in the selectors. index() would return -1 if there is no match.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.current').index('section');
```

See the docs on [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the original element relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

change like this

```
var sections = 'section';
```

your code is doing this and its wrong

```
alert($($('section')+'.current').index());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see how that helps. setting var sections = 'section'; does nothing more than create a text string.

Comment: if you should use like this var sections = $('section');
then use just this  alert(sections.hasClass('current').index());