# Issue with index of all matched elements in DOM

Tags: jquery

I realize this may be a duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723129/getting-the-index-of-a-current-element-across-all-matched-elements-in-the-dom)

I'm trying to select the current index of any element with the same class.

Here is an example of my problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/jMB45/2/

I followed the suggestion in the other question however I'm still receiving a '-1' on the second set of elements.

HTML

```
<div class="members">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>                                          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="profiles">
    <div class="profile active">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="bio col-md-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tempor et sapien non vestibulum. Ut dictum arcu libero, eu aliquet massa bibendum id. Sed a venenatis nisl, id pretium purus. Phasellus porta faucibus arcu in pellentesque. Maecenas viverra, lectus quis euismod cursus, elit magna blandit augue, nec tincidunt lectus orci sed nunc. Suspendisse est justo, ullamcorper in leo sed, facilisis varius tellus. 
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="photo col-md-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="profile"></div>
</div>
<div class="members">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 ">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="member">
                <span>Name</span>
                <span>Last Name</span>
                <span>Position</span>
            </div>
        </div>                                          
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.member').click(function() {

        $('.member').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var members = $('.member');

        var current = members.index($('.active'))
        $('#index').html(current);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var members = $('.member').click(function() {
        members.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var current = members.index(this); //pass the dom reference here
        $('#index').html(current);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/27QqY/)